# How to know which value is bigger?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Which is bigger between $2018^{2019}$ or $\ 2019^{2018}\ $?

When taking logs of both sides and  I get:

$2019\log(2018)\ $ and $\ 2018 \log(2019)$

I know $\log 2019\gt \log 2018$ so does this mean that $2019^{2018}$ is the biggest one? And did I do it properly?

Comment: Already asked zillion times. Rewrite in the form $\frac{\log x}x<\frac{\log y}y$.

Comment: Think about the function $\frac{ln(x)}{x}$

Comment: but how do i know which one is less than the other? @YvesDaoust

Comment: Hint: increasing or decreasing function ?

Comment: Rewrite your question this way: Which is larger, $2018^{1/2018}$ or $2019^{1/2019}$, and this question has been asked here before (with different numbers but the same method of solution).

Comment: @RoryDaulton sorry, I'm just failing to see how $2018^{2019}$ is the same as  $2018^{\frac{1}{2018}}$

Comment: Take the $2018 \cdot 2019$th root of each side of your equation and you end up with my equation. (I.e. take each side to the power of $\frac 1{2018\cdot 2019}$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to take logarithm of both expressions is good. Now
\begin{align}
2019\cdot\log 2018&=\color{blue}{2018\cdot\log 2018}+\log2018\tag1\\[2em]
2018\cdot\log 2019 &=2018\cdot\log \left(2018\cdot{2019\over2018}\right) \\
&= 2018\cdot(\log 2018 + \log{2019\over 2018}) \\
&=\color{blue}{2018\cdot\log 2018}+2018\cdot\log\left({2019\over 2018}\right)\tag2
\end{align}

As both $(1)$ and $(2)$ have their first addend (in blue) the same, what is greater:

$$\log2018,\ \text{or}\tag3$$
$$2018\cdot\log\left({2019\over 2018}\right)\ ?\tag4$$

Comment: from where are you getting the blue part that you added on?

Comment: I didn't add it - the first one is from writing $2019$ as $(2018 + 1)$ and using the distributive law. The second blue part is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f(x)=\ln x/x$ is decreasing for $x>e$.

Comment: im sorry im just still confused. are you saying i should do $\log 2018/ 2019 < \log 2019/2018$?

Comment: sorry, I finally understood what you meant. thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, $\log 2019>\log 2018$ is simply equivalent to $2019>2018$ by monotonicity of the logarithm, and this does not prove the claim.